# get psycopg2 errors in python3

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I've the psycopg2 version 2.6.1
i want to fetch some errors, but it dont work as excpected:

```
try:
    pgconn = psycopg2.connect(database="foobar", host="dbtest.example.de", user="postgresss")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    print(psycopg2.OperationalError.pgerror)
   .....:     
<member 'pgerror' of 'psycopg2.Error' objects>
```

or:

```
try:                       
    pgconn = psycopg2.connect(database="foobar", host="dbtest.example.de", user="postgresss")
except psycopg2.OperationalError:
    print(psycopg2.OperationalError.diag)
   .....:     
<attribute 'diag' of 'psycopg2.Error' objects>
```

How can i see the correct message like "no pg_hba.conf entry for host xyz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *reference the exception* instance:

```
try:
    pgconn = psycopg2.connect(database="foobar", host="dbtest.example.de", user="postgresss")
except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but why I can't use print(psycopg2.OperationalError) ?

Comment: @colttt cause `psycopg2.OperationalError` is an exception class, but `e` is an instance.